# How to upgrade cordova version in iOS build server for Visual Studio 2013?

Tags: ios, cordova, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-cordova

When i use VS2013 to develop Cordova project, then i wanna to remote compile for iOS on Mac OS, but i got the following error:

Error   62  Invalid build request: The build request for cordova version 4.3.0 is not supported by the iOS build server. The server is installed with cordova version 4.0.0.

The reason why i upgrade develop version to newly version,but iOS build server was older then mine. i'm already tried to update -g cordova, but still no work, how do i upgrade iOS build server to 4.3.0 for vs2013 remote build?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the full documentation [on updating the remote agent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn757054(v=vs.140).aspx#ios).
Stop the current remote agent and run

> sudo npm install -g vs-mda-remote --user=$USER

where $USER is replaced by your user name on the Mac. When you run the command, you will be prompted to enter your password as well.

The global installation (-g) switch is recommended but not required.

You'll need to start the updated remote agent and potentially re-configure the connection in VS if you are running in Secure mode.

Comment: Interesting. I did not know about the vs-mda-remote parameter. That's good to know!

Answer (score 0):

The [command](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.html) should be

> sudo npm update -g cordova

Sudo on OSX and Linux has to be used with the -g parameter. [-g parameter](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/npm) is for global installation.

Comment: Thanks eomer, but no luck, when i startup build server "vs-mda-remote --secure false", then it shows me installedCordovaVersion: 4.0.0, although i update use the command upgrade Cordova version from 4.0.0 to 5.0.0. Could i direct BuildManager to newly verion for the build?